# Почему коллектор смайликов не работает на личные сообщение?

Tags: javascript, discord

У меня есть код, который отлично работает на сообщение на серверах, но отказывается работать на личных сообщениях.

мой код:

```
let msg = await message.author.send('Вы согласны ?');
await msg.react("✅");
await msg.react("❌");

let collector = msg.createReactionCollector({time: 15000});

collector.on("collect", async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction._emoji.name === "✅") {
        console.log('1');
    } else {
        console.log('2');
    };
    console.log(reaction);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в том, что я не дал боту разрешение на личные сообщение.

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, //<<
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, //<<
    ],
});
```